# Fastest method for Number of Combinations with a product of 336?

Tags: combinatorics, alternative-proof

> Derek’s phone number, 336-7624, has the property that the  three-digit
>   preﬁx, 336, equals the product of the last four digits, 7 × 6 × 2 × 4.
>   How many seven-digit phone numbers beginning with 336 have this
>   property?

So I went number by number and found the number of combination including each of the numbers.

For when the four digits include 1 the only way is for the numbers to be in any combination of 1,6,7,8. And there are **4!** arrangements

For when the four digits include 2, there are two ways (without using 1). Either 2,4,6,7 or 2,3,7,8, and each has 4! arrangements totaling to **2(4!)** arrangements.

For when the four digits include 3, there is one way (not including 2, or 1), the numbers 3,4,4,7. There are **4!/2** ways to arrange those.

There are no more ways to make 336 without using 1,2, or 3.

Adding all the cases ends up with **84**.

This is the correct answer, but my question is, what is the fastest way to do this, or is there no other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a faster way.  You didn't say how you found the four digit possibilities.  If you factor $336=2^4\cdot 3 \cdot 7$ you can find the four digit possibilities rather easily.  One digit has to be $7$.  One has to be $3$ or $6$.  Then you split the remaining $3$ or $4$ factors of $2$ among two digits.

Comment: Oh, well this is a lot faster then my method of trial and error for the 4 digit possibilities at least, and that took me most of the time.